# Subfigure indices in Russian

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, subfloats

When I make some subfigures, they are indexed as (a), (b), (c),... Is there a way to index them with Cyrillic letters, i.e. (а), (б), (в),...?

[image: Example of what I mean]

The code I use for this example is as follows:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{mathtext}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\hyphenation{ма-те-ма-ти-ка вос-ста-нав-ли-вать}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[width=0.8\textwidth]{caption}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=30mm, right=20mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm, bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[width=0.8\textwidth]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./pictures/Lenna}
        \caption{Какая-то картинка с русской подписью.}
        \label{fig:lenna1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./pictures/Lenna}
        \caption{Some figure with an English caption.}
        \label{fig:lenna2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Two figures with subindices.}
\end{figure}

Figure reference looks like this: рис. \ref{fig:lenna2}. What I want is something like рис. 1б.

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\asbuk` for the subfigure counter:

```
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\asbuk{subfigure}}
```

**Complete Code:**

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{mathtext}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\hyphenation{ма-те-ма-ти-ка вос-ста-нав-ли-вать}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[width=0.8\textwidth]{caption}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=30mm, right=20mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm, bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[width=0.8\textwidth]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\asbuk{subfigure}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Какая-то картинка с русской подписью.}
        \label{fig:lenna1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Some figure with an English caption.}
        \label{fig:lenna2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Two figures with subindices.}
\end{figure}

Figure reference looks like this: рис. \ref{fig:lenna2}. What I want is something like рис. 1б.

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Does one really need to define the counter? For me, simply adding `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\asbuk{subfigure}}` seems to work.

Comment: The `\asbuk` command is already defined by `babel-russian`. You don't need `enumitem`, `\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\asbuk{subfigure}}` is sufficient.

Comment: @leandriis Oh, you're right! I edit it.

Comment: What if I am not using `babel`? How do I define `\asbuk` then?

Comment: @Milos You could ask a new question for that with a link to this one.

Comment: @dexteritas I did. If you want to answer it, here it is: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506469/how-to-number-subfigures-in-serbian-cyrillic .